# Acceso a formulario en otra libreria de la misma solucion (error de referencia cruzada)

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto heredado de otros programadores en .NET 
La solución tiene varios proyectos en teoría separados por funcionalidad, con referencias entre ellos.

El problema que tengo es de acceso a un formulario de otra librería, que no esta referenciada en el proyecto en el que estoy trabajando y al referenciarla me indica que se produciría una referencia cruzada.

¿hay alguna forma de referenciar localmente ese formulario? supongo que existe una buena practica para esto.
Gracias

Comment: vertificaste que en la libreria del formulario que intentas acceder, no hay una referencia a la libreria en la que estas?

Comment: En lo personal, yo evito dividir los proyectos por funcionalidad, justamente debido a que siempre van a surgir situaciones de referencias circulares. Mas bien, prefiero dividir los proyectos por capas (datos, presentación, etc.) y usar los namespaces para organizar la funcionalidad.  En cualquier caso, si deseas una recomendación concreta a tu problema, te sugiero de incluir un ejemplo concreto con código para entender bien tu situación.

Answer (score 0):

Sin saber exactamente que recursos estás utilizando en cada proyecto, creo que la mejor manera de resolver eso es sacando esa funcionalidad común a una tercera librería e incluirlo en los dos proyectos en los que la necesites.

Comment: Hola, para poner un poco en contexto, el desarrollo es un erp que incluye como digo varios proyectos, en los que estoy trabajando son Entorno (que tiene los formularios para una gestion de roles y usuarios) y el proyecto Main (que tiene una gestion de contactos/sujetos). Desde la gestion de usuarios (proyecto Entorno) necesito lanzar el formulario de sujetos (en el proyecto Main), pero como digo no puedo agregar una referencia a Main, pues éste ya tiene una referencia a Entorno...no se si queda mas claro el caso. De todas formas me veo pasando la gestion de usuarios al proyecto Main.